# Mongoose Cant update nested object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my Mongoose schema.

```
book_schema = mongoose.Schema({
    book_name: {
        "type": String
    },
    pages: {
        "type": Object,
        "default": {}
    }
});
```

This is my document look like.

```
{ "book_name": "some book", 
  "pages": {
      1: {"lenght": 7, "text": "bla bla"}, 
      2: {"lenght": 11, "text": "bla bla bla"}
  }
}
```

And this is code that find document and change value.

```
Book.findOne({book_name: "some book"}, function(err, book){
    book.pages[1].lenght = 10; ##change 7 to 10
    book.save(function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

Code above can't change the value for some reason. I tried to change the other its worked just fine.

Answer (score -1):

Use the **[`update()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html)** method together with the **[`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)** operator to change the value. For example

```
Book.update(
    {book_name: "some book"}, 
    {$set: { "pages.1.lenght": 10 }}
    ,function (err, result){
        if (err) console.log(err);
        console.log(result);
    });
```

---

For non-static keys, create the update document using the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) to create the property, e.g.

```
var key = 1,
    updateObj = {};
updateObj["pages."+ key +".lenght"] = 10;
Book.update(
    {book_name: "some book"}, 
    {$set: updateObj}
    ,function (err, result){
        if (err) console.log(err);
        console.log(result);
    });
```

Comment: What should I do if the key is not static ?

Comment: @bookotl You could create the update document as indicated in my updated answer above.